# Install MySQL 5.6 on CentOS 6.3 gone WRONG

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, rpm, mysql5.5

I am trying to install MySQL 5.6 on CentOS 6.3 64bit using the .rpms provided by MySQL. I downloaded all the 64bit linux rpms into `/usr/local/src/mysql` and performed `rpm -Uvh *`.

The installation gave an error which I cant find out the error msg anymore. So I tried doing `rpm -Uvh *` again and it says

```
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]

package MySQL-devel-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64 is already installed
package MySQL-embedded-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64 is already installed
package MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64 is already installed
package MySQL-shared-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64 is already installed
package MySQL-client-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64 is already installed
```

Doing `rpm -e MySQL*` states that they are all not installed:

```
error: package MySQL-client-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
error: package MySQL-devel-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
error: package MySQL-embedded-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
error: package MySQL-server-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
error: package MySQL-shared-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
error: package MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.6_m9-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

I tried starting mysql with `/etc/init.d/mysql start` and `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` but the error returned was no such file or directory.

I tried `rpm --rebuilddb` and tried installing and removing but get the same error.

I'm kind of stuck now as to what to do next. Any suggestions?

---

### Update

I managed to get mysql installed by uninstalling and reinstalling the rpm.

Now when I try to start mysql,

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/[FAILED]mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid).`
```

I tried `mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.bak` and `/etc/init.d/mysql start` but that gave the same error.

Comment: Why aren't you using your package manager?

Comment: My package manager `yum` does not have the version of MySQL 5.6 that I want, only 5.1.

Comment: `rpm -qa --qf "%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n" | grep -i mysql`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx spoiler: you can use yum install on .rpm files

Comment: `tail -20 /var/log/mysqld.log`?

Comment: @quanta `no such file or directory`

Comment: @Nyxynyx: `grep error /etc/my.cnf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have SELinux enabled?  It's possible that the MySQL packages are not built to play nice with SELinux (not uncommon for 3rd party packages) and that it is blocking access to creating the PID file.  A quick and dirty test would be to set your SELinux context to Permissive (or Disabled)

```
# setenforce permissive
```

If that is not the case then have a look at the file permissions themselves.

For more information on SELinux:
[Red Hat SELinux Documentation for RHEL6](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/index.html)
[SELinux Project Wiki](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

Querying the rpmdb uses the package *name*, not the package *filename*. You can get the package name from a package file with `rpm -qp --qf "%{name}\n" <file>`.

Answer (score 1):

The packages are probably installed, but if they're the ones you downloaded from mysql.com then the actual package names are in all lowercase, even though the *file* names are in mixed case.

With that out of the way, the mysql.com packages are not 100% binary compatible with CentOS and a lot more than this will likely break. If you don't absolutely *need* 5.6 then it's probably best to use 5.5 from a trustworthy repo such as remi, until such time as compatible packages become available.

Comment: I require the `FULLTEXT` feature of Innodb in 5.6. Updated original post!